# What are the hypersonic Normal shock relationships?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, shock

I am learning about hypersonic flow now and there seems to be a lot of discussion about the oblique shock relationships as the Mach tends to be very large.
I was wondering what happens to the normal shock relationships as the Mach number tends to be high and I can't seem to find anything about it. Is it because it is not possible to have a normal shock at hypersonic speeds?